# Rsync speeds over two debian servers with 10Gb NIC

Tags: debian, ssh, rsync

I'm using this rsync command on my new debian/openmediavault server in order to get all data moved from the old one onto this one:

```
rsync -hazP --stats -e "ssh -T -c aes256-gcm@openssh.com -o Compression=no -x" root@10.10.10.15:/srv/27829c9c-dbc1-4408-a111-56dbcd8f0ec0/media/ /srv/mergerfs/norman_pool2/media
```

In both instances, the data is in a unionfs or mergerfs pool. 10.10.10.15 is the IP of the NIC on the source server which should make it communicate over 10Gb only since that port is plugged into the 10Gb NIC on the new server with a DAC cable. The only other interfaces are the main 1Gb NICs which each have a line going to my router/switch

The new server is intel I3 12100 with 32GB ram, the old is Dell R710 with dual xeon L5664 CPUs and 32 GB ram. They both show low CPU utilization and ram utilization during the process, but I'm not seeing more than 15MB/s on larger files, 5-10MB on smaller ones. I think the highest I've seen is 18MB/s which seems insanely slow for a direct 10Gb connection

Is there anything I'm not thinking of, or anything the command could use to speed things up even more

Comment: What's the average disk transfer speeds that you usually see when you're not running `rsync`?

Comment: @Kusalananda this new server hasn't had much done with it, but earlier I tested it with some images that were around 60MB a piece and I did an scp from one server to the other which gave me 12MB/s and then 4 instances of 72MB/s

Comment: hm aside from not expecting to see an explicit cipher spec here, and thinking that disabling compression will be nice once you exceed these rates significantly (put both into your ~/.ssh/config, maybe, under a new HostName directive?), I don't see things that look suspicious. So, first instinct is to blame strange routing or a misconfigured MTU

Comment: @MarcusMüller good point, maybe I should play with MTU on the openmediavault side. My iperf tests seem to get about 9Gb/s on the NICas

Comment: don't play – set to the same size as the other end of the cable

Comment: @MarcusMüller Both OMV web GUIs have 9000 as the MTU for the 10Gb ports

Comment: I'll assume not using `-e …` to compare speeds is not an option?

Comment: Good point, the same command that i was using before, just minus the -e option and its following string, was giving about the same speed

Comment: Remove the compression flag. With 10Gb/s network you don't need or want that

Comment: @roaima I think that was a typo but I installed 10Gb/s NICs into each server and then they each have the motherboard default 1Gb/s NIC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edit: oops, forgot the argument to tar, so that it does tar something...*

Rsync is especially good to update a repository, especially if only part of files have changed (such as growing log files, etc), but here you say you want everything copied over.

As there is low cpu use on both source and destination machines, and you need all the data to be moved you could maybe see some improvements using a simpler tool, such as tar?

Have a ssh key on the destination server's ~destuser/.ssh/authorized_keys, and then simply:

```
( cd /somesourcedir/ && tar czf - ./ ) | ( ssh destuser@destserver "cd /somedestdir/ && tar xzf -" )
# send the full content of /somesourcedir/ into /somedestdir/
# Do use `z` (gzip) option only if most of the data can easily be compressed.
# If most of the data is videos or jpegs or already compressed files, take out both z
# and it will be lighter on the cpu and maybe even a bit faster
```

And do not interrupt it ... as there is no way to continue a tar from a stopping point (especially here where the remote tar is on a separate process)...

If you do interrupt it, you should find clever ways of only sending the probably incomplete last file sent, and the following missing files and directories, which involves some clever uses of shell commands... or use rsync again to finish the job?

Be careful to use regular ssh, and especially do not add any compression (and especially do not use any -t (or variant thereof) giving a terminal emulation as it would mess up with the tar output and modify the remote files).

I believe you could also add a : | pv | , instead of just | , to get some information on the throughput speed ( pv is: pipe viewer) ... but I don't remember pv's options to show a simple MB/s information (iirc, one option allows you to give it, if you know it, the expected total size to be transfered, but if the tars have the z option the information will be very different)

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a good option. Although, ```( cd /VideoPodcasts/ && tar cf - ) | pv | pv (ssh root@10.10.10.13 "cd /srv/mergerfs/norman_pool2/media/VideoPodcasts/ && tar xf -" )``` gives a syntax error that ssh is an unexpected value so I'll have to play with this a bit

Comment: you need spaces after ( and before ) and you have : pv | pv ssh , instead of the correct : pv | ssh

Comment: (sorry i re-do the comment as I introduced a typo, and forgot to tell tar to tar something (./, ie the whole current dir) ) : try : `( cd /VideoPodcasts/ && tar cf - ./ ) | pv | ( /usr/bin/ssh root@10.10.10.13 "cd /srv/mergerfs/norman_pool2/media/VideoPodcasts/ && tar xf -" )`  # use the full path for ssh, found with : `which ssh`  or `type -all ssh` in bash, to avoid functions or aliases introducing maybe some extra unwanted options such as : -t or compressions

Comment: @OlivierDulac Re your latest comment: `which ssh` would search the directories in `$PATH`, which means that if it says `ssh` is in `/bin/ssh` (or any other place), then the shell will find it in that place when you use `ssh` without a path. It is therefore nonsensical to use the path returned from `which ssh` to execute `ssh`, unless `PATH` is somehow changed between running `which` and running `ssh`.

Comment: @Kusalananda : The difference is that if there is an alias or function with name `ssh`, for exemple: ssh() { /bin/ssh -o someoptions "$@" ; } : that will be run when you use `ssh` (in bash: function superseeds aliases, and aliases superseeds commands found in $PATH). Putting the full path instead ensures that they only run the `/whateverpath/ssh` command itself, with default options, bypassing any potential alias or function named "ssh". Another way in bash would be : `command ssh` instead of `ssh`, but it is more bash specific than using the full path (which is more portable and predictable)

Comment: Ah, I see your point, although a user should arguably _know_ that they have written an `ssh` alias, but never mind. Yes, using `command ssh` would be preferable.